# websocket connection fails with vaadin

Tags: websocket, vaadin, vaadin7

i programmed a website that acts as websocket client for my android app that acts as websocket server in my WiFi network. originally i wrote it just with javascript/jquery and it already worked without any problems, but because i got fascinated by vaadin, i totaly rewrote it with vaadin and it already works on a local tomcat 7 or 8, but not on the remote tomcat 7 or 8. the onOpen method of the android server never gets called. the server of the jquery version is the same as the one with the vaadin version, but when i try to start my page i get this error and the page does not connect to my phone, although i am able to ping my mobile phone:

```
vaadinPush.debug.js:11276: WebSocket connection to 'ws://serialcall.rdroid.info/PUSH/?v-uiId=3&v-csrfToken=18797926-2579-4599-a0af-29729f9deb88&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.1.5.vaadin4-jquery&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json;%20charset=UTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

this is the the vaadin log info on the non working remote server

```
371ms   Queuing push message: {"csrfToken":"0b112c17-8c20-4307-8d2b-871589d720a6", "rpc":[["505","com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.UIServerRpc","resize",["923","1280","1280","923"]],["506","org.vaadin.jouni.animator.client.AnimatorServerRpc","preserveStyles",[{"useKeyframeAnimation":false, "animationTarget":"546", "duration":"2000", "delay":"0", "css":{"properties":{"opacity":"0.2"}}, "easing":"DEFAULT", "id":"25", "iterationCount":"1", "preserveStyles":true}]]], "syncId":1}
720ms   Push connection closed
721ms   Push connection using primary method (websocket) failed. Trying with long-polling
1131ms  Push connection established using long-polling
1132ms  Sending push message: {"csrfToken":"0b112c17-8c20-4307-8d2b-871589d720a6", "rpc":[["505","com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.UIServerRpc","resize",["923","1280","1280","923"]],["506","org.vaadin.jouni.animator.client.AnimatorServerRpc","preserveStyles",[{"useKeyframeAnimation":false, "animationTarget":"546", "duration":"2000", "delay":"0", "css":{"properties":{"opacity":"0.2"}}, "easing":"DEFAULT", "id":"25", "iterationCount":"1", "preserveStyles":true}]]], "syncId":1}
1154ms  No onClose was received before reconnect. Forcing state to closed.
```

this is how the vaadin log message looks on the working local server:

```
1008ms  Making UIDL Request with params: {"csrfToken":"6be927e0-1e38-407d-b8fe-744d83a23e43", "rpc":[["1614","com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.UIServerRpc","resize",["923","1280","1280","923"]],["1615","org.vaadin.jouni.animator.client.AnimatorServerRpc","preserveStyles",[{"useKeyframeAnimation":false, "animationTarget":"1655", "duration":"2000", "delay":"0", "css":{"properties":{"opacity":"0.2"}}, "easing":"DEFAULT", "id":"20", "iterationCount":"1", "preserveStyles":true}]]], "syncId":1}
1009ms  Queuing push message: {"csrfToken":"6be927e0-1e38-407d-b8fe-744d83a23e43", "rpc":[["1614","com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.UIServerRpc","resize",["923","1280","1280","923"]],["1615","org.vaadin.jouni.animator.client.AnimatorServerRpc","preserveStyles",[{"useKeyframeAnimation":false, "animationTarget":"1655", "duration":"2000", "delay":"0", "css":{"properties":{"opacity":"0.2"}}, "easing":"DEFAULT", "id":"20", "iterationCount":"1", "preserveStyles":true}]]], "syncId":1}
1303ms  Push connection established using websocket
```

i use tootallnate as websocket client and i have the same tomcat-version and the same javaversion on the server and on my local computer, even when i disable the firewall. no exception is thrown and could not find out why it does not work.

any ideas what i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that you have deployed your app into the Jelastic instance without the Public IP, that means all requests were proxyed by nginx. As mentioned [here](http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/10/29/shared-resolver-and-public-ip-in-jelastic/), you must obtain the Public IP to let your app work with WebSockets in Jelastic.

Comment: but jelastic was just an additional try, after it failed on my normal server. i got exact the same error messages on both.

Comment: i removed the information about jelastic in my post, because i realised that its just confusing.

Comment: Seems that application server is closing the websocket connection. 
Did you tried to change the timeOut value in the app server or calling **sendPing** every 30 or so seconds?

Comment: the android server is never opened at all. the onOpen method is never reached.